# How to align button in responsive navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have the following nav bar code in "Navbar2.jsx":

```
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import NavItem from './NavItem';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { navVariants } from '../utils/motion';
import styles from '../styles';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';

const menu_list = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'About', href: '/', current: false },
  { name: 'Contact', href: '/', current: false },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

const Navbar2 = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return(
    <motion.nav
      variants={navVariants}
      initial='hidden'
      whileInView='show'
      className={`${styles.xPaddings} py-8 relative z-30`}
    >
      <div className='absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01' />
      <div className={`${styles.innerWidth} mx-auto flex justify-between gap-8`}>
        <Link href='/' className='z-30 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100'>
          <Image
            src='/headset.svg'
            alt='logo'
            width={30}
            height={30}
            className='object-contain'
          />
        </Link>
        <h2 className='font-extrabold text-[24px] leading-[30px] text-white'>
          TITLE
        </h2>
        <div className='hidden sm:flex space-x-4'>
          {menu_list.map((item) => (
            <Link href={item.href} className={classNames(
              item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
              'rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium'
            )}
            aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
            >
              {item.name}
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      <div>
          <button type='button' onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} className='sm:hidden inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white'>
            <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
            {isOpen ? (
              <XMarkIcon className="block h-6 w-6 " aria-hidden="true" />
            ) : (
              <Bars3Icon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
            )}
          </button>
          {isOpen && (

            <div className='space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2'>
              <div className='rounded-md ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden'>
                {menu_list.map((item) => (
                  <Link href={item.href} key={item.name} className={classNames(
                        item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                        'block px-4 py-2 text-sm'
                      )}
                      aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                  </Link>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar2;
```

Which produces the "responsive" navbar, the issue I'm having is that the dropdown menu on the mobile menu shifts the "X" button to the side, I want the menu to just "drop down" below the hamburger button which turns into an "X", without moving.

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

[image]

I tried adding "absolute" to the button className but it didn't change anything. Also tried "justify-end" which also didn't change anything.

I've uploaded the full project on git [here](https://github.com/Mischa-bc/nextjs_template1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing the `<button>` class from `inline-flex` to `flex`, so that it becomes a block layout, then apply `margin-left: auto` with the `ml-auto` class so that the `<button>` will always be aligned to the right:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-950">
  <nav class="py-8 relative z-30">
    <div class="absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01"></div>
    <div class="mx-auto flex justify-between gap-8">
      <a href="/" class="z-30 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="logo" width="30" height="30" class="object-contain" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="font-extrabold text-[24px] leading-[30px] text-white">
        TITLE
      </h2>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white ml-auto">
          <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="block w-6 h-6">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2">
          <div class="rounded-md ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
            <a class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-4 py-2 text-sm">
              {item.name}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I used your code and replaced "justify-center" with "justify-end" and it worked